# Let the roles I specify use the command

Tags: command, discord.js

I made my Discord bot for Minecraft but i have command "satışilanı" I want this command to only use people with the role I specified, but I can't anyone can help me?

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const moment = require('moment');

const cooldown = new Set();
exports.run = async(client, message, ops) => {
    let args = message.content.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ');
    message.delete();
    if (cooldown.has(message.author.id && message.guild.id)) {
        return message.channel.send('**:x: [YAVAŞLA] :x:** Çok hızlı ilan gönderiyorsun! **5 Dakika** beklemelisin!');
    }
    if (args.length < 1) {
        return message.channel.send(`**İlan detaylarını iletmelisin!** ${message.author}`);
    }
    if (message.member.roles.some(role => role.name === 'Whatever')) {
        return message.channel.send(`**Ticaretçi rolüne sahip olman gerekiyor!**`);
    }   
    cooldown.add(message.author.id && message.guild.id);
    setTimeout(() => {
        cooldown.delete(message.author.id && message.guild.id);
    }, 300000);
    let guild = message.guild;
    const cnl = client.channels.get('613397862545358888');
    message.channel.send(`**Hey, ${message.author}, biz satış ilanını yayınladık! :white_check_mark:`);
    const embed2 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor(`MuzGO Pazar ${message.author.tag} tarafından kullanıldı!`, message.author.displayAvatarURL)
        .addField('**MuzGO Satış İlanı :pencil: **', `**İlanı Gönderen: :speaking_head: ** ${message.author.tag}`,`İlanın Gönderildiği Kanal` , '#『』satılık-ürünler')
        .setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL)
        .setFooter(`${moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')}`)
        .setColor("#ffd700");
};
```

Here is probably wrong i cant understand.

```
if (message.member.roles.some(role => role.name === 'Whatever')) {
            return message.channel.send(`**Ticaretçi rolüne sahip olman gerekiyor!**`);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
message.member.roles.some(role => role.name === 'Whatever')
```

This returns a Boolean, `true` if the member has the role, `false` if they don't have it. So, to send a message if the member doesn't have the role, you have to add a `!` to inverse the condition:

```js
if (!message.member.roles.some(role => role.name === 'Whatever')) {
        // if the condition above is false, so the member doesn't have the role
        return message.channel.send(`**Ticaretçi rolüne sahip olman gerekiyor!**`);
}
```

Comment: No problem! You can set the topic as answered by marking my answer as correct

Comment: Why not invert the equality check in the `some` method?

Comment: Because it means if you have another role than 'Whatever', it won't work. However you can invert the equality check but replace `some` with `every`. Like:
`if (message.member.roles.every(role => role.name !== 'Whatever')) {`